# How to move a trained SSAS mining structure model to a different database?

Tags: sql-server, machine-learning, ssas, classification, dmx-ssas

I have many candidate models in my mining model development SSAS database which I would like to move to my production SSAS database, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that for trained models without having to re-train the model once it is in the new database. How can I retain the model content when moving across databases?
I think that I can use the DMX EXPORT/IMPORT to a file location for this, but it is clunky and I am working off of a SQL cluster where I don't have a clear path to a static location. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a full database backup to disk and restore then you might try a Synchronize. It will incrementally copy a database from one SSAS instance to another without landing on disk as a backup file first:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174928.aspx